# Maximize similarity of files by inserting white space

Tags: diff

I have two trace text files from a PIN Tracer to compare byte by byte for an algorithm I am working on.
They are largely the same, but differ in some places messing up the alignment. For example, here is a part of log file 1:

```
18: 1    
19: 2  
20: 3
21: 4
22: 5
23: 6
24: 7
25: 8
26: 9
27: 10
28: 11
29: 12
30: 13
31: 14
32: 15
33: 16
```

and here is part of log file 2:

```
18: 0
19: 1
20: 2
21: 3
22: 4
23: 5
24: 6
25: 7
26: 8
27: 9
28: 10
29: 11
30: 12
31: 13
32: 14
33: 15
```

As you can see, the values are off by one, causing the file size to be off by one as well. I have a program that performs a byte-by-byte comparison, and so after the

> 26: 9

the comparisson is off by a byte. diff and beyondcompare figure out that this is happening. Can diff or another tool insert whitespace to equalize the file size and allow me to continue the byte-by-byte comparison? I can't go line-by line, because sometimes a whole line may be missing, and so I need whitespace to fill that gap too.

I want to point out that the file does not consist only of numbers, but a variety of text. Some of the file contents look like this:

```
[!] Function 0x7fffe55aea80 is filtered, no tracing 
[R]        11     0x100000734 0x100227fd8 size= 8 value=0x00007fffe55aea80
[I]        11     0x100000734    call qword ptr [rip+0x22789e] ff 15 9e 78 22 00
```

So, is there a utility to insert whitespace to maximize similarity between text files?

I appreciate anyone who take the time to read this post. Doubly so for any suggestions.

Comment: `diff` has various options to ignore whitespace differences.  e.g. `-b` aka `--ignore-space-change` and `-w` aka `--ignore-all-space`.

Comment: First: Thanks. However, that is almost the exact opposite of what I need. I need it to add whitespace where there are missing bytes....

Comment: just reverse the diff

Comment: I don't understand how reverse the diff is supposed to work. Could you add a little more detail, please?